# Why can I click an NSButton if it's not first responder?

Tags: c++, cocoa, first-responder, nsresponder

I'm trying to implement a class like `NSResponder` in C++, on thing I don't understand is this:

All keyboard/mouse interactions are sent to the first responder, so if for example a NSTextField is currently the first responder, how does another `NSButton` in the same view know it's been clicked? If the textfield doesn't want the mouse click, it will send it to it's superview, and it's superview will send it to the view controller. So the mouse-clicked event never reaches the button.

This is probably pretty obvious but I can't wrap my head around it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All keyboard/mouse interactions are sent to the first responder

This is incorrect. From the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW4):

> The window object … dispatches most events to the NSView object
>   associated with the user action in an NSResponder message such as
>   mouseDown: or keyDown:. …
>
> The object receiving an event message differs slightly by type of
>   event. For mouse and tablet events, the NSWindow object dispatches the
>   event to the view over which the user pressed the mouse or stylus
>   button. It dispatches most key events to the first responder of the
>   key window.

This distinction between the paths of mouse and key events is repeated in the relevant sections specific to those types of events.

A button "knows" when it's been clicked because it is the thing which was clicked. The window figures out what was under the mouse cursor using the `-[NSView hitTest:]` method.

Comment: How about if the mouse moves out of the button, how does the button know the mouse is not there anymore if the mouse events are not sent to him. For example if the image was changed to a hover image and the button needs to change it back to the normal image when the mouse moves out?

Comment: First, it's quite likely that the button starts an internal event loop in its `-mouseDown:` implementation. So, it gets *all* events until the mouse-up. But even if it doesn't, the same document I linked to says, a bit further down: "Mouse-dragged and mouse-up events are typically sent to the same view that received the most recent mouse-down event."

Comment: I read your answer a few times, and it took me awhile to understand the distinction you were making, so here it is in black and white for future searches: 1) For `mouse clicks`, the thing under the mouse receives the event message, e.g. an NSButton.  2) For (most) `key presses on your keyboard`, the first responder of the window receives the event message.